# FileNotFound error (JSON file)

Tags: java, json, tomcat, servlet-3.0

I am having an error FileNotFound, even the file(JSON file) is in the project.When I run (Run as Java application) my java web app in compiler(eclipse) it works absolutely fine no error. But when I run the app (Run on server) after deploying on TOMCAT server, it throws an error FILENOTFOUND, The file (JSON file) doesn't exist.File was in the project after this error I put it in the main folder still got the same error, then I placed my file (JSON file) in src, literally I tried putting the file in every possible directory/folder but still got the same error. Why its not recognising the JSON File?

Comment: Post your project hierarchy

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the full path of a JSON file so it can be recognized by project, even the file is in your project directory.

Comment: No you don't. You can provide a relative path, provided it is accurate.

Comment: But it didn't work for me, what worked for me, I mentioned it above